# How to validate Integer value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I need to validate input field, it should be integer(0-100), if max_seat = 5 then min_seat should be less than or equal to max_seats.

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal" id="table_info" name="table_info"  method="post" action="">                                                       
<input class="span6 " id="max_seat"  name="default_seats" type="text" />
<input class="span6 " id="min_seats"  name="default_seats" type="text" />
</form>
```

and the jquery is looking like this, how to create rules in this type validation, thank you

```
    $("#table_info").validate(
    {
        rules: {
            min_range :"required integer",
            max_seats:"required integer"
        },
        messages: {
            max_seats: "* Required",
            min_range: "* Required",
        }
    });
```

Comment: You need to write a custom validation method that compares the value in one field to another field.

Comment: yes, but i dont know where to do those validation thats why i asked this question bro

Comment: Use `$.validator.addMethod()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not how you declare multiple rules.  (This shorthand style can only be used with *one* rule.)

```
rules: {
    min_range :"required integer",
    max_seats:"required integer"
}
```

You must declare each rule separately.  And for an integer, you can use [the `digits` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/digits-method/).

Your HTML is also not valid for this plugin...

```
<input class="span6 " id="max_seat"  name="default_seats" type="text" />
<input class="span6 " id="min_seats"  name="default_seats" type="text" />
```

Each field must contain a *unique* `name` attribute and you would declare your rules based on that `name`.  (Declare the `messages` option similarly)

```
rules: {
    min_seats: { // <- this is the NAME attribute of the field, not ID
        required: true,
        digit: true
    },
    max_seats: { // <- this is the NAME attribute of the field, not ID
        required: true,
        digit: true
    }
}
```

To compare the two fields, you must use [the `.addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) and declare your new custom rule the same as above.